# When using `DispatchQueue.main` as a parameter/variable it's impossible to satisfy the `@MainActor` requirements

Tags: swift

When using `DispatchQueue.main` as a parameter/variable it's impossible to satisfy the `@MainActor` requirements.

See the following code:

```
final class MyClass {
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.someMainFunction() // legal
        }

        let queue = DispatchQueue.main
        queue.async {
            assert(Thread.isMainThread) // true
            self.someMainFunction() // Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'someMainFunction()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
        }

        queue.async { @MainActor in // Converting function value of type '@MainActor () -> ()' to '@convention(block) () -> Void' loses global actor 'MainActor'
            assert(Thread.isMainThread) // true
            self.someMainFunction()
        }

        // or another example

        doSomethingAsync(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
            assert(Thread.isMainThread) // true
            self?.someMainFunction() // Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'someMainFunction()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
        }
    }

    func doSomethingAsync(queue: DispatchQueue, something: @escaping () -> Void) {
        queue.async {
            something()
        }
    }

    @MainActor
    func someMainFunction() {
    }
}
```

Any ideas for workarounds? The only thing I've found is using `@MainActor(unsafe)` on `someMainFunction()` but I really don't want to do that.

Comment: Why not just use `Task.detached { @MainActor in ... }`?

Comment: @BradleyMackey legacy code predating Tasks. But this appears to be a unfixable scenario and a gross oversight by the Swift team :(